# Redirect subdomain to sub-folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to write rewrite rule, to redirect subdomains to sub-folder.

Example: ***subdomain.domain.io*** should be redirected to ***domain.io/apps/subdomain***, and  ***test7.domain.io*** should be redirected to ***domain.io/apps/test7*** and so on...

in .htaccess file I can catch the subdomain via following condition:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.io$
RewriteRule ?
```

But how to make redirection?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.io$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ apps/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

- `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` is used to prevent looping of this rule.
- `%1` is back-reference of subdomain text captured in 2nd `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I met following issues:
1. it makes infinite loop
2. it still keeps subdomain in redirected host. I need to redirect test.domain.io to domain.io/apps/test, but it keeps subdomain.

Comment: No, I need to keep subdomain.

I've changed the script to following:
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.csbuilder\.io$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http ://csbuilder.io/apps/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

but now it redirects to that url, like if I had set R flag.
I have space after http just to prevent putting link in this site.

Comment: You cannot use `http://` in target URL otherwise it will redirect. Use the rule I suggested i.e. `RewriteRule ^ apps/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]`

Comment: I get a login screen once I click on that URL. I trust `http://cslab.csbuilder.io/` and `http://csbuilder.io/` point to same site root directory.

Comment: I missed pointing them to same directory. Subdomain was pointed to apps folder. Now it works fine. Thanks very much!

Comment: One last question. This rule also applies on apps.csbuilder.io, which is another subdomain. How to add exception for apps subdomain?

Comment: Just change 2nd condition to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!app\.|www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.io$ [NC]` to add `app.` in exclusion.

Comment: Great! Only one issue. when I use sub-folder on sub-domain, it keeps subdomain. http://cslab.csbuilder.io works fine, but http://cslab.csbuilder.io/cs-admin redirects to cslab.csbuilder.io/apps/cslab/cs-admin/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160235/discussion-between-syom-and-anubhava).

Comment: May I know why all of a sudden you removed acceptance from this answer? Is there any issue?